# How to handle max database connections with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

Below is Hibernate configuration from Hibernate.xml

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
         .....
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>
```

Below is code from GenricDaoImpl class (code 1)

```
@Override
public T save(T t) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(t);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return t;
}
```

and other code from project (code 2)

```
   Query executeQuery = getSession().createQuery(hql);
   UserProfileuser  =  (UserProfile) executeQuery.uniqueResult();
```

Above both codes I am using in project. My question is which coding need to follow ? code 1 or code 2 to avoid max connections error.? I can connect max 1000 connections with database. But in some cases it is going more than 1000 . So i want to maintain database connection minimum.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Using 1000 database connections doesn't sound like a very good idea. Each extra database connection requires extra RAM and increases the likelihood of concurrency issues (deadlocks).

Since you use C3P0 you should have a max connection size:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
```

If you run out of connections then it may be because:

- you don't close the Hibernate `Session`, and the associated JDBC connection doesn't get released to the pool
- your queries take too long to execute and so they don't release connections fast enough

I recommend using a [connection pool size utility](https://vladmihalcea.com/connection-pool-sizing-with-flexy-pool/), such as [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) to understand better the database connection usage patterns.

Regarding the two choices:

- The 1st example contradicts the automatic session management support offered by Spring.  When you use Spring you should not manage Hibernate Sessions yourself. You should let the transaction manager call the appropriate Hibernate initializing callbacks on a new transaction boundary.

  In your example, if the session throws an exception, the session will not be closed and the connection might be dangling around. That's because you haven't used a try/finally block for releasing the Session.
- The 2nd example is better, but you need to wrap it into a `@Transactional` service.

Comment: can you tell me ,whether it is due to from code 1 or code 2. ? and if i do not close connection from code 1 then will it create new connection every time.? or will it use existing opened one.?

Comment: It's true.As curiosity i want to know , In code 1, i am opening connection and closing it properly, then why it is increasing connection count.? why connection's are not getting closed immediate by calling close() .? Connections getting closed after some specific time , but till that time it reaches to max connection.

Comment: How do you know you have more than 1000 connections at once? Most db only allow several hundred only.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing. I have take D8 Tier billing plan. From google developer console --->Storage--->cloud sql----> Active Connections. On that page it show graphs of number active coonections